# How to make a simple stock price simulation process more efficient in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization

I have some very simple code written to simulate a stock price assuming random movement between -2% and +2% a day (it's overly simplistic but for demonstration purposes I figured it was easier than using a GMB formula).

The issue I have is that it's very slow, I understand that it's because I'm using double loops. From what I understand I might be able to use vectorization, but I can't figure out how.

Basically what I did was create 100 simulations assuming 256 trading days in a year, each day the previous stock price is multiplied by a random number between .98 and 1.02.

I currently do this using a nested for loop. As I gather this is not good but as a novice I'm having a hard time vectorizing. I've read about it online and from what I understand basically instead of using loops you would try to convert both of them into matrices and use matrix multiplication but I'm unsure how to apply that here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
from numpy import exp, sqrt, log, linspace
from random import gauss
from random import uniform
import pandas as pd


nsims = 100
stpx = 100
days = 256
mainframe = pd.DataFrame(0, index = list(range(1,days)), columns = list(range(1,nsims)))
mainframe.iloc[0] = stpx
for i in range(0, nsims-1):
    for x in range(1, days-1):
        mainframe.iloc[x, i] = mainframe.iloc[x-1, i]* uniform(.98, 1.02)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization can be tricky when one calculation relies on the result of a previous calculation, like in this case where day x needs to know the results from day x-1. I won't say it can't be done as quite possibly somebody can find a way, but here's my solution that at least gets rid of one of the loops. We still loop through days, but we do all 100 simulations at once by generating an array of random numbers and making use of numpy's element-wise multiplication (which is much faster than using a loop):

You will need to add the following import:

```
import numpy as np
```

And then replace your nested loop with this single loop:

```
for x in range(1, days-1):
    mainframe.iloc[x] = mainframe.iloc[x-1] * np.random.uniform(0.98, 1.02, nsims-1)
```

Edit to add: because you are using a very simple formula which only involves basic multiplication, you actually can get rid of both loops by generating a random matrix of numbers, using numpy's cumulative product function column-wise, and multiplying it by a DataFrame where each value begins at 100. I'm not sure such an approach would be viable if you started using a more complicated formula though. Here it is anyway:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nsims = 100
stpx = 100
days = 256

mainframe = pd.DataFrame(stpx, index=list(range(1, days)), columns=list(range(1, nsims)))
rand_matrix = np.random.uniform(0.98, 1.02, (days-2, nsims-1)).cumprod(axis=0)
mainframe.iloc[1:] *= rand_matrix
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this, this is definitely a good start, I understood 0 about vectorization before but now I have a better sense.

As a follow up, you mentioned that it can be tricky when n relies on n-1, so if I was to modify my function so that let's say if stock price is below 80, the range of the movement increases such that the random generator becomes: random.uniform(.92, 1.08) as a simulation for volatility of the movement increasing (sort of)? 

This kind of thing would NOT be doable with vectorization?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes - I can’t think of any way to vectorize that as we need to know that we are below 80 before we know what range we’re generating our random number from, so we can’t just multiply two matrices together.